# User-Managed Access for Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, user-permissions

I am trying to find a gem that handles User-Managed Access for a Rails App. There are many role based gems but they don't quite meet the need. The best scenario example I am thinking is like this:

I have a model with a list of Actions that can be used for different methods (i.e. RECORD_CREATE and RECORD_UPDATE). I want to allow users to perform these actions or prevent users from performing these actions. In addition, I'd like to create group permissions in the same way but still have the ability to add additional permissions for a user without creating a different specific group. All of this, I would like to be able to control from inside the app and not from a ruby file in lib. Is there such an animal? I've been looking but to no avail. If there isn't, does anyone want to help me make one?

Comment: I think [Cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) meets your requirement. We have the ability to customise this based on our need. Refer the [Wiki](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki) for more details.

Comment: @HarrySuren. It looks like a very good solution but I'm having trouble conceptualizing it in execution. I will probably build a test app and install the gem to test it out. I have a homemade solution that works real well. I have a listbox of actions and can turn those on/off for each user or group from inside the app. Then I put a helper method at the beginning of each action to test permissions for that action. Uses only about 10 lines of code plus 1 line for each authorization test.

Comment: Found this article. Very interesting and would like to hear more opinions on it. https://www-old.amg.tv/blog/strongbolt-why-and-how-we-built-our-own-rails-authorization-framework

Comment: Can you share your helper and solution for this problem as a gist file please?

Comment: i added an answer with my home-grown solution. check it out and let me know if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51415669/8503822

Answer (score 0):

I have found a really interesting gem called [Strongbolt](https://github.com/605data/strongbolt) that is based on a Grant gem for Record Based Authorization. Still figuring out the intricacies but seems like a pretty powerful option.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a home-grown solution if anyone is interested....

lib/permissions.rb

```
module Permissions
  def all_permissions
    @all_permissions ||= self.activities + Activity.joins(:permissions).where(permissions: {group: self.groups})
  end

  def update_permissions(permissions)
    return if permissions.nil?
    self.permissions.destroy_all
    permissions.collect do |key, permission|
      self.permissions.create!(activity_id: permission)
    end
  end

  def authorized?(activity_code)
    self.all_permissions.include?(Activity.find_by(code: activity_code))
  end
end
```

lib/groups.rb

```
module Groups
  def update_groups(groups)
    return if groups.nil?
    self.group_memberships.destroy_all
    groups.each do |key, value|
      group = Group.find_by(id: value)
      self.groups << group if group
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
include Permissions
include Groups
```

in code...

```
rails g scaffold group name description
rails g model group_membership group:belongs_to user:belongs_to
rails g model activity name code description
rails g model permission group:belongs_to user:belongs_to activity:belongs_to
```

app/models/activity.rb

```
default_scope -> { order(:name) }
has_many :permissions
has_many :users, through: :permissions
validates :name, presence: true
validates :code, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

app/models/group.rb

```
include Permissions
has_many :permissions
has_many :activities, through: :permissions
has_many :group_memberships
has_many :users, through: :group_memberships
validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb (create and update)

```
@user.update_permissions(params[:user][:permissions]) if params[:user][:permissions].present?
@user.update_groups(params[:user][:groups]) if params[:user][:groups].present?
```

app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

def authorized?(activity)
  current_user.authorized?(activity)
end

def authorize(activity)
  if !current_user.authorized?(activity)
    redirect_to root_path, flash: { warning: 'You do not have permission to access this area.' }
  end
end
```

then the syntax to check permission for the user is either

```
if authorized?('PERMISSION_SHORT_CODE')
```

or...

```
authorize('PERMISSION_SHORT_CODE')
```

or any variation. The 'PERMISSION_SHORT_CODE' is any unique identifier used to find the activity in question. I personally add activities via rails console when I add a feature to the site and then I can restrict that feature as needed. 'USER_ADD', 'USER_DESTROY', 'USER_EDIT', etc. Here is a snippit of code I use to show and edit permissions under users#edit.

app/helpers/users_helper.rb

```
def permissions_list(object, method, instance, options = {})
  capture do
    options.collect.with_index do |c, index|
      if instance.groups.any? { |g| g.activities.include?(Activity.find(c[1])) }
        concat check_box_tag("#{object}[#{method}]#{index}", c[1], true, disabled: true)
      else
        concat check_box_tag("#{object}[#{method}]#{index}", c[1], instance.activities.include?(Activity.find(c[1])))
      end
      concat content_tag(:label, "#{c[0]}".titleize) + tag(:br)
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/users/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="listbox">
  <%= permissions_list(:user, :permissions, @user, Activity.all.order(:name).collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}) %>
</div>
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css(.scss)

```
.listbox
  overflow: hidden
  overflow-y: scroll
  margin: 10px
  height: 250px
  width: 300px
  border: 1px solid
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px
```

I hope this helps someone and/or someone can look at it and see a better way to do it. Thanks you guys for all the help!!